# How to input a file, and then filter it and output the result into a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that you can upload a Javascript file and it removes all comments from the document. This works perfectly. However below that I have two `textareas`. One is where the user pastes their code, and the same function to remove all comments is run on that code and the updated code is pasted in the other `textarea`. However the result comes out as undefined. What is wrong with my code. Please help me!

```js
function fileUploaded() {
  var myUploadedFile = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(myUploadedFile, "UTF-8");
  reader.onload = function(evt) {
    var documentNew = evt.target.result.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "\n");

    document.getElementById("myFile").addEventListener("change", fileUploaded, false);

    var str = documentNew;
    var lines = str.split('\n');

    var filterred = lines.filter(function(line) {
      return line.indexOf('//') != 0;
    });

    filterred = String(filterred).replace(/;/g, "; \n");

    $("#answerDocument1").html(filterred);
  };
};
document.getElementById("myFile").addEventListener("change", fileUploaded, false);
$("#doc").keyup(function(evt) {
  var doc = $("doc").html();
  var documentNew = String(doc).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "\n");

  var str = documentNew;
  var lines = str.split('\n');

  var filterred = lines.filter(function(line) {
    return line.indexOf('//') != 0;
  });

  filterred = String(filterred).replace(/;/g, "; \n");

  $("#answerDocument2").html(documentNew);
});
```

```css
textarea {

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Upload A Javascript Document</h3>
<input type="file" id="myFile">
<textarea id="answerDocument1"></textarea>
<br><br>
<hr>
<br><br>
<textarea id="doc"></textarea>
<textarea id="answerDocument2" readonly></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used...

`filterred = filterred.join("").replace(/;/g, "; \n");`

Instead of...

`filterred = String(filterred).replace(/;/g, "; \n");`

Because `filterred` is an array, and not a string, and if you convert it into a string it comes out joined by commas.

I have also used `$("#doc").val();` instead of `$("doc").html();`, because it is the value of the `<textarea></textarea>` that I am getting. That makes the undefined message go away.

```js
function fileUploaded() {
  var myUploadedFile = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(myUploadedFile, "UTF-8");
  reader.onload = function(evt) {
    var documentNew = evt.target.result.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "\n");
    var str = documentNew;
    var lines = str.split('\n');

    var filterred = lines.filter(function(line) {
      return line.indexOf('//') != 0;
    });

    
    filterred = filterred.join("").replace(/;/g, "; \n");
    $("#answerDocument1").html(filterred);
  };
};
document.getElementById("myFile").addEventListener("change", fileUploaded, false);
$("#doc").keyup(function(evt) {
  var doc = $("#doc").val();
  var documentNew = String(doc).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "\n");
  var str = documentNew;
  var lines = str.split('\n');

  var filterred = lines.filter(function(line) {
    return line.indexOf('//') != 0;
  });

  filterred = filterred.join("").replace(/;/g, "; \n");
  $("#answerDocument2").html(filterred);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Upload A Javascript Document</h3>
<input type="file" id="myFile">
<textarea id="answerDocument1"></textarea>
<br><br>
<hr>
<br><br>
<h3>Paste Code</h3>
<textarea id="doc"></textarea>
<h3>Copy Formatted Code</h3>
<textarea id="answerDocument2" readonly></textarea>
```